# How to make a div grow with content?

Tags: html, css

Pertaining to html, how do I make a div container grow with the content instead of manually defining a width and height.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="someimage.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

No matter what the dimensions of logo are, container does not grow with it. :( 
How would I fix this, or can it be fixed?

Answer (score 47):

If you don't define width and/or height, the div element grows along with its content. Unless his content is set to absolute! If the content is set to float, you have to set to the container

```
overflow:hidden
```

in order to let it grow!

Comment: Very interesting! Why does this work? Can you provide more documentation about this?

Answer (score 16):

The default behaviour for divs is to fill the entire available width. A few ways to override this:

- set `display: inline-block` (not IE-friendly)
- float it (with the side effect of, well, floating it)
- set `display: inline` (but that's almost never what you want)
- set `position: absolute`
- hard-code a width (no dynamic width though)

As a last resort, consider javascript.

Comment: Can you elaborate how would js help here?

Answer (score 6):

Use the magical css property called "flex", it is really amazing

```
yourDiv{
display:flex;
}
```

Just make sure that the children are not position: absolute because this will not work with flex.

Comment: needs more information...  as your answer stands it doesn't work with nested divs of variable height.

Comment: Of course it does , i use it everyday , unless the div are display absolute !

Comment: that might have been handy information to include in your answer...  so, " 
needs more information... as your answer stands it doesn't work..."

Comment: by the way...   absolute is a position property value, not a display property value

Comment: ok , well the value flex to the display property will allow you arrang items inside the div invoked on. IT will help you to keep all the items for an example to the left or to the right or even spread them with equal spaces between then , horizontally or vertically. 
Obviously if the divs are position fixed or sticky or absolute this will  not work with flex. Here is more detailed inforamtions because i cant write eveything here, it is too long.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You can specify min-width and min-height and DIV will adjust width / height as the content changes (of course, not below min width/height).

[Working code pen example](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/grXbAP)

Most important css properties from the code (DIV is editable, so just type in text and it will grow with it by width / height):

```
 min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
```

Comment: If the content is larger than the minimum height, the min-height property has no effect. not sure how this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you used `float` it prevents `<div>` to grow up with content so you can use `clear` after `float` and it will work.

```
<div class="clear-fix"></div>

.clear-fix{
   clear: both;
}
```